# Correct syntax for a async/await function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, apollo

I've defined a [resolversMap](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers.html#Resolver-map) and I need to use async/await for that as I'm doing a DB request. I'm failing with the correct syntax:

```
const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    signinUser: (root, { username, password }) => {
      const db = DB.getDB()
      const Users = db.collection('users')
      const user = Users.findOne({ username: username })
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    async signinUser: (root, { username, password }) => {
      const db = DB.getDB()
      const Users = db.collection('users')
      const user = await Users.findOne({ username: username })
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

It's working if I define the function like this:

```
async signinUser (obj, args) {}
```

But what is the difference between this and `signinUser: (obj, args) => {}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is close, but you actually need to declare `async` in front of the arrow function:

```
const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    signinUser: async (root, { username, password }) => {
      const db = DB.getDB()
      const Users = db.collection('users')
      const user = await Users.findOne({ username: username })
    }
  }
}
```

Regarding your question as to why `async signinUser (obj, args) {}` works, this is an ES6 shorthand for the following:

```
signinUser: async function signinUser(obj, args) {}
```

See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) on Object Initializers (specifically, take a look at the new, ES2015 syntax)

Comment: Thanks. But what is the difference to `async signinUser (obj, args) {}`?

Comment: I updated answer to reflect the difference -- it's actually ES6 shorthand for initializing the object.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the function with `async signinUser (obj, args) => {}` because it is no longer a normal function. An async function returns a promise, while a normal function returns what you returned.

If it is not set to async, javascript disables `async xyz()` in it.

Answer (score 0):

At your `signinUser: (obj, args) => {}` you will have the same context, see `=>`, search for `arrow function`